# Find $(a,b)$ such that $x^2-bx-a$ is irreducible and $\begin{bmatrix}0&a\\1&b\end{bmatrix}$ has order $8$

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

I believe I might be having a bit of trouble with a question that asks me to find the values of $a$ and $b$ such that the polynomial $x^2-bx-a$ is irreducible and the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & a \\
1 & b 
\end{bmatrix}$ has order $8$.

This is not a homework question in any class that I am taking. This is regarding a research project that I am planning on working with a professor for which I have almost no clue what I am doing.

Comment: Not sure your justifications for including zero personal input hold water but... The polynomial $x^2-bx-a$ is the characteristic polynomial of the matrix  hence the hypothesis that the eighth power of this matrix is the identity and that $x^2-bx-a$ is irreducible, implies that $x^2-bx-a$ divides $x^8-1$. Can you finish?

Comment: Working on it. Will get back to you as soon as I am done. Thanks!